# Automatic Email by Status in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax-error

The following code has an error with line 7, `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(“Active Projects”);`

This code is being used to send email when project is completed.

```js
function checkValue(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(“Active Projects”);

  var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange(“E”).getValue();

  var rangeEdit = e.range.getA1Notation();

  if (rangeEdit == “E”)

  {

    if (valueToCheck = Completed)

    {

      MailApp.sendEmail(“0000 @gmail.com”, “blah”, “test” + valueToCheck + “.”);

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: What is the error??have you checked the browser console?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the smart quotes (`“”`) to normal quotes (`""`):

```
function checkValue(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Active Projects");

  var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("E").getValue();

  var rangeEdit = e.range.getA1Notation();

  if (rangeEdit == "E")

  {

    if (valueToCheck = Completed)

    {

      MailApp.sendEmail("0000 @gmail.com", "blah", "test" + valueToCheck + ".");

    }

  }

}
```